# Determine whether Linux distro uses .deb or .rpm via browser?

Tags: linux, browser, operating-system, user-agent, navigator

I don't believe this is possible from the research I've done, but I'm asking in the hopes of being wrong.

I'd like to determine whether to serve a `.rpm` or `.deb` installer to a user automatically based on their user agent string.

Specifically, is there anything in `window.navigator` that I'm overlooking that might be helpful for this? If anyone has ideas outside of `window.navigator` I'd of course be interested in those too.

Comment: User agent strings can be can be unreliable and faked. See, for example, [User-Agent-Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/) (and friends).

Comment: I know and I'm okay with that. I was just wondering if there was any way to attempt to serve the proper file. The fallback would, of course, be to allow users to manually download the correct file.